# iOS quick look PDF how to go to specific page

Tags: ios, pdf, quicklook

Is it possible to open a PDF document on an specific page number using quick look framework?
or do I have to use another reader?

Thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QuickLook framework does not provide support for this feature. You have to use another PDF viewer framework.